# Setting Jenkins up to run ssh commands-- where to store SSH keys for a user with login disabled?

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins

I'm trying to generate a keypair to allow a jenkins server to ssh to another (via the ssh-steps plugin if that's relevant).  The public key will go in the authorized keys on the target host. My understanding is that it should be simple, something like:

```
sudo su - [jenkins user]
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C jenkinsuser@jenkinshost
```

Then save the key to `/home/jenkinsuser/.ssh/id_rsa` and grab the public key to add to authorized keys on the host.

What I'm seeing is that `sudo su - jenkinsuser` doesn't work, and `/etc/passwd` reveals the shell for this user is set to `/bin/false`, to disable login as I understand it.

With that in mind I'm looking for a best practice on designating a spot for the ssh key since the user has login disabled and therefore no home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a built-in [credentials store](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) which is the most appropriate place to put SSH keys used by Jenkins jobs.  The credentials store is designed for storing various kinds of credentials used by Jenkins jobs such as SSH keys, usernames/passwords, and API keys.  The credentials store allows delegation of access and ensures sensitive credentials do not get written out to job output.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to be root to run the key generation script.

I usually store all my keys in `/etc/ssh`. This is out of the home directory and I think `/etc` is the most accurate directory for that.